Fatal error Server error HTTP 503 while pushing file to GIT repo
I am trying to push folder of size 2GB to GIT repository
I am using below commands
git init
git config lfs.contenttype false
git config http.version HTTP/1.1
git checkout -b main
git add "path to folder"
git status
git commit -m "model folder 2GB"
git remote add origin "GIT repository path"
git push -u origin main

but getting below error
    Fatal error: Server error &{%!!(string=https) %!!(string=) %!!(*url.Userinfo=&{accenturecio08  false}) %!!(string=dev.azure.com) %!!(string=/"GIT Repository Path"/info/lfs/objects/ee44444c2b82c12ccaeb7fd1a6fd1e082a5e5f56331546dfea5ffc61011aaca0) %!!(string=) %!!(bool=false) %!!(bool=false) %!!(string=) %!!(string=) %!!(string=)}s(MISSING) from HTTP 503

Anyone knows how to resolve this issue?

I can't make sense of that second paragraph, is the formatting off perhaps? BTW: Did you even read the description of the tag you applied? Is that really what you mean?

503 is a server-side error. Is there any more information you haven't posted?

@JimRedmond
I'm encountering a similar error to the one described in this link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Git-Push-Fatal-error-Server-error-503/10247264?q=Error+AADSTS50076
I've already tried the suggested solution from the link, but unfortunately, it hasn't resolved the issue.
